# How can I wait for a Firestore database request to complete?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to loop through retrieving a bunch of documents from Cloud Firestore in a for loop with Javascript. The problem is that the delay in the data call means that one element is repeatedly examined. How can I wait for the document to be retrieved before calling code on that document?

```
for (i = 0; i < following.length; i++) {

            db.collection('users').doc(following[i]).get().then(function (doc) {
                insert += "<p class='follower'>" + doc.data().firstName + " " + doc.data().lastName + "</p>";
            })
        }
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to explore the await new promise and use within the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get()` method for Firestore documents is asynchronous and returns a Promise. You need to wait for those promises to resolve before you can iterate through the values. Here's an example that does so:

```
const usersReference = db.collection("users");
const promises = following.map(fid => usersReference.doc(fid).get());
return Promise.all(promises).then(docs => {
  let insert = "";
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    insert += `<p class='follower'>${doc.data().firstName} ${doc.data().lastName}</p>`;
  });
  console.log(insert);
});
```

Comment: Worked almost perfectly, just made a small edit to correct a typo. Thank you!

Comment: This is not working for me ... could you please make an example in which you don't already have the uid's ?